# React Native encrypt a message with publicKey. Convert encrypted to base64

Tags: javascript, react-native, encryption, public-key

I need to do, for react native, encryption of a message.
I tried several libraries, but none worked.

(
JSEncrypt (not supported)

NODERSA (didn't work)

expo-crypto (I couldn't set the public key because I have my key)

react-native-rsa (it didn't work either because of the key)
)

I wonder if anyone knows a way to do this!?

---

I have the public key and the message.
I need to encrypt the message with the public key and pass it to base64.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this solution for react native. You can use [nodejs-jsencrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-jsencrypt) to encrypt the message in base64format.

After installation, import the library and follow the steps below (check the image); if your backend is ready to decrypt using a private key with JSEncrypt library, this should work.

[code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ0BG.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow
Please add codes as text in the questions/answers please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)